# Alternative to __super__ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, super

I'm trying to get [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgf5fkfL/1/) I found to work in Firefox. It's working fine in Chrome, but in Firefox all the options appear as blank lines. I suspect the issue is `__super__` on line 8, since from Googling around I read that it only exists in Javascript because of CoffeeScript. (the fiddle does not use backbone.js, which I understand implements its own `__super__`.) I'd prefer not to have any dependences other than jQuery and select2. So, what other ways could this be written?

Here's the full js code from the fiddle:

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require(
  ['select2/data/array', 'select2/utils'],
  function (ArrayData, Utils) {
    function CustomData($element, options) {
      CustomData.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
    }

    function contains(str1, str2) {
      return new RegExp(str2, "i").test(str1);
    }

    Utils.Extend(CustomData, ArrayData);

    CustomData.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {
      if (!("page" in params)) {
        params.page = 1;
      }
      var pageSize = 50;
      var results = this.$element.children().map(function(i, elem) {
        if (contains(elem.innerText, params.term)) {
          return {
            id:[elem.innerText, i].join(""),
            text:elem.innerText
          };
        }
      });
      callback({
        results:results.slice((params.page - 1) * pageSize, params.page * pageSize),
        pagination:{
          more:results.length >= params.page * pageSize
        }
      });
    };

    $("#ioList").select2({
      ajax:{},
      allowClear:true,
      width:"element",
      dataAdapter:CustomData
    });
  });
```

Comment: It probably is some kind of `super` emulator. Natively it would be `super($element, options)`.

Comment: if it's extending `ArrayData` than probably just `ArrayData.call` instead of `CustomData.__super__.constructor.call`

Comment: @PatrickEvans that seems to be working. Unfortunately it didn't make the page work in Firefox, so I suppose that's not the only problem.